# Windows Firewall inbound Rules not active after Turn on the AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server, windows-firewall

Windows Firewall inbound Rules not active after Turn on the AWS instance

so I am not able to RDP into this Instance, when ever power on the machine(Domain machine). also there is no custom Rules defined under domain level. so all are default

[Active Rules at the time of power ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8BEw.png)

After I remote using Session manager , then initiate the restart then the firewall rules gets activated and able to do RDP.

[Active Rules after a reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBb5S.png)

But Each time I will shutdown the instance if there is no load on the server, then turn on whenever is needed.

Comment: I think there is something stopping or not running after you turn on the instance, did you try GPUPDATE /FORCE from the session manager to see if that helps.